# Can't tell which pin is hot and which is ground on connector datasheet

Tags: circuit-design, identification, components, component-selection

I want to use the following bnc connector: 1-1634612-0 by TE Connectivity.
I am looking at the datasheet but I can't tell which pin goes to ground and which pin I connect to get an input. I linked the datasheet below the picture.

[image]

https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1634612&DocType=Customer+Drawing&DocLang=English&PartCntxt=1-1634612-0&DocFormat=pdf

Comment: Like any coax connector, case and cable screen is GND, centre pin is hot.

Comment: If the question is one that actually needs to be asked, then the answer is dictated by whatever is going to be connected to the other end or whatever application standard/need it must meet.  As that's a plastic body it's not entirely a given that either side is "ground ground" vs simply being a signal *reference* - see for example an Ethernet card where there's no galvanic path from the shell to the computer chassis or circuitry, because the interface is transformer isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector is the BNC type, used with coaxial cable. Normally the outer connector is shield ground, and center connector is signal.

In the footprint diagram, the pin that is centered on the connector body is the 'signal' pin. The pin to the left is connected to the shield, which is also the connector shell.

Answer (score 2):

The bnc connector is a general purpose part. It is not specifically designed for ground on either pin.

Ground designation is application specific. You can make the shell ground or the center ground. Its up to you.

But typical application in video and networking and test clips is that center is positive and the shell is ground. The shell can also mate with the enclosure which is typically also grounded. Check your application before you decide.

Comment: While this is true ... I've never ever seen an application where the outer (connects to screen on a coax cable) is "hot" and the inner is GND.

Answer (score 0):

The pin descriptions are in the table in the bottom right.

- 1 is the signal contact.
- 4 is the tail or GND connection.

Comment: Those are item / description / material notes, not pin numbers.